# Precision error while comparing two dataframes in scalatest

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql, scalatest

I am trying to compare actual data frame with expected in scala test.
Both data frames have a count column of type Int ,but while comparing two frames I am getting precision error as below:

```
      Row
+--------+-----+--------+
|agerange|count|datadate|
+--------+-----+--------+
|   30-39|    1|20190906|
+--------+-----+--------+
was considered not equal to
+--------+-----+--------+
|agerange|count|datadate|
+--------+-----+--------+
|   30-39|    1|20190905|
+--------+-----+--------+

Row
+--------+-----+--------+
|agerange|count|datadate|
+--------+-----+--------+
|   80-89|    2|20190906|
+--------+-----+--------+
was considered not equal to
+--------+-----+--------+
|agerange|count|datadate|
+--------+-----+--------+
|   80-89|    2|20190905|
+--------+-----+--------+

Row
+--------+-----+--------+
|agerange|count|datadate|
+--------+-----+--------+
|   90-99|    1|20190906|
+--------+-----+--------+
was considered not equal to
+--------+-----+--------+
|agerange|count|datadate|
+--------+-----+--------+
|   90-99|    1|20190905|
+--------+-----+--------+

schema tolerance:
  * precisions by column
      [*, 1.0E-6]
  * ignore nullable flag for each column
  * ignore column order
```

Can someone please suggest where I am going wrong?

Below is the code snippet for actual df:

```
val windowSpec = Window
      .partitionBy("agerange")

    rangeDf
      .select("agerange")
      .withColumn("count", count("agerange") over windowSpec cast("Int"))
      .distinct()
      .withColumn("datadate", lit(runningDate.runningDateString))
```

Code for Expected DF:

```
val expectedDf: DataFrame = Seq(
      ("80-89", 2, "20190905"),
      ("30-39", 1, "20190905"),
      ("90-99", 1, "20190905")
    ).toDF("agerange", "count", "datadate")
```